# programmatically control bluetooth status light

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to control the bluetooth status light on modern laptops, and how would I go about this?

If it's manufacturer/model specific, any tips on finding details for particular models?  I'm particularly interested in Dell and Asus models.

EDIT: just to be clear, I don't want to control the bluetooth hardware at all, just the status light.  In fact, the status light often exists even when there is no bluetooth radio install.

Comment: You're going to have to get some system schematics from somewhere. Dunno where. Also, keep in mind that it's entirely possible, even *likely* that you cannot control it programmatically without rewiring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a "Status" light indicates the status of something. so unless you have direct access to the hardware and can bypass that "something" you will need to control it to alter its state. This implies that you do in fact need to control the bluetooth hardware. Now if the light is present on some models when the radio is not installed, what does the light indicate in that case? "Bluetooth installed / not installed"? If so, then to control the light you may need to fake out the system so that it appears to it that bluetooth is installed when it is not. It all sounds very iffy, but perhaps possible.

I'm guessing that you may just want some already available light (not necessarily bluetooth) to indicate status of something you care about, rather than what it was originally intended for? If so, perhaps there is some other light that is easier to hack?

Comment: I know that some email software uses the Scroll Lock for notifications, so I was hoping it might be possible access the bluetooth light too... perhaps I'm being overly optimistic!